Почему в char записывается больше симоволов, чем объявлено
Мне нужно ввести текст определенной длины и как бы разбить его на куски, чтобы сделать перенос. С одним переносом все работает, но при двух переносах этот второй кусок записывает еще и первый зачем-то
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct students {
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    char patronumic[50];
    int year;
    int first_grade;
    int second_grade;
    int third_grade;
    int fourth_grade;
    int fifth_grade;
    int len_name;
    int len_surname;
    int len_patronumic;
};

int AddStudent(int k) {
    cin.get();
        cout<<"Enter student's name: "; 
        cin.getline(student[k].name,50);   
        student[k].len_name=10-(strlen(student[k].name));
        cout<<"Enter student's surname: ";
        cin.getline(student[k].surname,50);
        student[k].len_surname=16-(strlen(student[k].surname));
        cout<<"Enter student's patronumic: ";
        cin.getline(student[k].patronumic,50);
        student[k].len_patronumic=16-(strlen(student[k].patronumic));
        cout<<"Enter student's year of admission: ";
        cin>>student[k].year;
        if (student[k].year<1959||student[k].year>2024) {
            do {
            FixStreamState();
            cout<<"Illegal input. Input command once more: ";
            cin>>student[k].year;
            } while (student[k].year<1959||student[k].year>2024);
        }
        cout<<"Enter student's 1st subject grade: ";
        cin>>student[k].first_grade;
        if (student[k].first_grade<2||student[k].first_grade>5) {
            do {
            FixStreamState();
            cout<<"Illegal input. Input command once more: ";
            cin>>student[k].first_grade;
            } while (student[k].first_grade<2||student[k].first_grade>5);
        }
        cout<<"Enter student's 2nd subject grade: ";
        cin>>student[k].second_grade;
        if (student[k].second_grade<2||student[k].second_grade>5) {
            do {
            FixStreamState();
            cout<<"Illegal input. Input command once more: ";
            cin>>student[k].second_grade;
            } while (student[k].second_grade<2||student[k].second_grade>5);
        }
        cout<<"Enter student's 3rd subject grade: ";
        cin>>student[k].third_grade;
        if (student[k].third_grade<2||student[k].third_grade>5) {
            do {
            FixStreamState();
            cout<<"Illegal input. Input command once more: ";
            cin>>student[k].third_grade;
            } while (student[k].third_grade<2||student[k].third_grade>5);
        }
        cout<<"Enter student's 4th subject grade: ";
        cin>>student[k].fourth_grade;
        if (student[k].fourth_grade<2||student[k].fourth_grade>5) {
            do {
            FixStreamState();
            cout<<"Illegal input. Input command once more: ";
            cin>>student[k].fourth_grade;
            } while (student[k].fourth_grade<2||student[k].fourth_grade>5);
        }
        cout<<"Enter student's 5th subject grade: ";
        cin>>student[k].fifth_grade;
        if (student[k].fifth_grade<2||student[k].fifth_grade>5) {
            do {
            FixStreamState();
            cout<<"Illegal input. Input command once more: ";
            cin>>student[k].fifth_grade;
            } while (student[k].fifth_grade<2||student[k].fifth_grade>5);
        }
    k++;
    return k;        
}
    void PrintList() {
    PrintLine();
    PrintHeader();
    int i=0,n;
    char name1[7], name2[7], name3[7], name4[7], name5[7], name6[7], name7[7];
    while (student[i].name[0]!='\0') {
        for (n=0; n<7; n++){
            name1[n]=student[i].name[n];
            name2[n]=student[i].name[n+7];
            name3[n]=student[i].name[n+14];
            name4[n]=student[i].name[n+21];
            name5[n]=student[i].name[n+28];
            name6[n]=student[i].name[n+35];
            name7[n]=student[i].name[n+42];
        }
        if (strlen(student[i].name)>=14&&strlen(student[i].name)<21) {
            PrintLine();
            cout<<"\n| "<<name1<<right<<setw(10-strlen(name1))<<" | "<<student[i].surname<<setw(student[i].len_surname)
            <<" | "<<student[i].patronumic<<setw(student[i].len_patronumic)
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].year
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].first_grade
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].second_grade
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].third_grade
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].fourth_grade
            <<" | "<<setw(17)<<left<<student[i].fifth_grade<<" |"<<endl;
            cout<<"| "<<name2<<right<<setw(10-strlen(name2))<<" | "<<setw(16)
            <<" | "<<setw(16)<<" | "<<setw(23)<<" | "<<setw(23)<<" | "<<setw(23)<<" | "
            <<setw(23)<<" | "<<setw(23)<<" | "<<setw(19)<<" |"<<endl;
            cout<<"| "<<name3<<right<<setw(10-strlen(name3))<<" | "<<setw(16)
            <<" | "<<setw(16)<<" | "<<setw(23)<<" | "<<setw(23)<<" | "<<setw(23)<<" | "
            <<setw(23)<<" | "<<setw(23)<<" | "<<setw(19)<<" |"<<endl;
        }
        else if (strlen(student[i].name)>=7&&strlen(student[i].name)<14) {
            PrintLine();
            cout<<"\n| "<<name1<<right<<setw(10-strlen(name1))<<" | "<<student[i].surname<<setw(student[i].len_surname)
            <<" | "<<student[i].patronumic<<setw(student[i].len_patronumic)
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].year
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].first_grade
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].second_grade
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].third_grade
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].fourth_grade
            <<" | "<<setw(17)<<left<<student[i].fifth_grade<<" |"<<endl;
            cout<<"| "<<name2<<right<<setw(10-strlen(name2))<<" | "<<setw(16)
            <<" | "<<setw(16)<<" | "<<setw(23)<<" | "<<setw(23)<<" | "<<setw(23)<<" | "
            <<setw(23)<<" | "<<setw(23)<<" | "<<setw(19)<<" |"<<endl;
        }
        else if (strlen(student[i].name)<7) {
            PrintLine();
            cout<<"\n| "<<student[i].name<<right<<setw(10-strlen(student[i].name))<<" | "<<student[i].surname<<setw(student[i].len_surname)
            <<" | "<<student[i].patronumic<<setw(student[i].len_patronumic)
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].year
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].first_grade
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].second_grade
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].third_grade
            <<" | "<<setw(20)<<left<<student[i].fourth_grade
            <<" | "<<setw(17)<<left<<student[i].fifth_grade<<" |"<<endl;
        }
        i++;
        for (n=0; n<7; n++) {
            name1[n]=name2[n]=name3[n]=name4[n]=name5[n]=name6[n]=name7[n]='\0';
        }
    }
    PrintLine();
    cout<<'\n'; 
    }

}

int main() {
    int k=0;
    int command{};
    do {
        PrintMenu();
        command=GetCorrectValue();
        switch (command) {
            case 1: cout<<"Entering student's info..."<<'\n'<<endl;
                k=AddStudent(k);
                break;
            case 2: 
                if (student[0].name[0]=='\0') {
                    cout<<"The group is empty. Try add a new student."<<endl;
                    break;
                }
                cout<<"Printing the list..."<<endl;
                PrintList();
                break;
            case 0: cout<<"The program is over. Goodbye!"<<endl; break;
            default: cout<<"Illegal command. Try again."<<endl;
        }
    } while (command);
    return 0;
}

Ввожу строку в 20 символов (asdfghjklasdfghjklas), в name2 действительно записываются вторые семь символов, но в конце почему-то добавляются еще и первые семь символов, выглядит в итоге это как-то так:
Printing the list...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Name    | Surname       | Patronumic    | Year of admission    | 1st subject grade    | 2nd subject grade    | 3rd subject grade    | 4th subject grade    | 5th subject grade |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| asdfghj | a             | a             | 2020                 | 5                    | 5                    | 5                    | 5                    | 5                 |
| klasdfgasdfghj |               |               |                      |                      |                      |                      |                      |                   |
| hjklas  |               |               |                      |                      |                      |                      |                      |                   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Пробовал выводить последовательно как идет запись в name2, на втором элементе вместе с буквой записывается еще какая-то ерунда, которая еще и меняется с каждым запуском:
 k
k klйm#┌▌aso►ў◄
klйm#┌▌asd►ў◄ klam#┌▌asd►ў◄
klam#┌▌asdfў◄ klas#┌▌asdfў◄
klas#┌▌asdfg◄ klasd┌▌asdfg◄
klasd┌▌asdfgh◄ klasdf▌asdfgh◄
klasdf▌asdfghj klasdfgasdfghj

Когда проверял, какую длину он мне в итоге выдал, то пишет 15. Но ведь в самом начале я объявил, что длина будет 7? Почему так?
Код возможно ломанный, я еще учу язык, но эту проблему я не понимаю совсем, как это фиксить. Может это я просто чего-то не понимаю

Ковыряться в таком коде никакого желания, но главное - вы нулевые символы часом не забыли? И еще: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@Harry помню про них, пробовал больше сделать массив, лучше не стало. А код я и так максимально сократил, оставил только части, где могут быть проблемы возможно

Что, тут, например? cout<<"Enter student's 5th subject grade: ";         cin>>student[k].fifth_grade;         if (student[k].fifth_grade<2||student[k].fifth_grade>5) {             do {             FixStreamState();             cout<<"Illegal input. Input command once more: ";             cin>>student[k].fifth_grade;             } while (student[k].fifth_grade<2||student[k].fifth_grade>5);         } И таких не имеющих отношения кусков множество... Да и еще, откровенно говоря, понять, что у вас за проблема (на что вы жалуетесь) проблематично. Не то на ввод, не то на вывод...
